# How to use redundant alias in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a query with join from 2 tables having similarly named index "time". I want to return the result with the same named index "time".

```
SELECT "tbl1"."a"                       "a", 
       "tbl1"."b"                       "b", 
       "tbl2"."c"                       "c", 
       COALESCE("tbl"."time", "tb2"."time") "time" 
FROM   "tbl1" 
       FULL OUTER JOIN "tbl2" 
                    ON "tbl1"."timestamp" = 
                       "tbl2"."timestamp" 
ORDER BY "time"
```

This query returns an error that "time" is redundant (in ORDER BY).

If I change alias "time" to something else - it will work. But I do want that query will return "time"

If I change ORDER BY to

```
ORDER BY COALESCE("tbl"."time", "tb2"."time")
```

It will also work, but as far as I understand it will do the search for Nones twice and extend execution time (isn't it?).

Comment: You can use that function call in your ORDER BY clause, it will not be executed second time.

Comment: What is the error you're getting. There is nothing wrong with your query.

Comment: "ERROR: column reference "time" is ambigious"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use positional column numbers instead of names:

---

```
SELECT "tbl1"."a"                       "a", 
       "tbl1"."b"                       "b", 
       "tbl2"."c"                       "c", 
       COALESCE("tbl"."time", "tb2"."time") "time" 
FROM   "tbl1" 
       FULL OUTER JOIN "tbl2" 
                    ON "tbl1"."timestamp" = 
                       "tbl2"."timestamp" 
ORDER BY 4;
```

---

This will also work for`GROUP BY`.

Comment: Wow! I didn't even knew it!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lateral join:

```
SELECT "tbl1"."a"                       "a", 
       "tbl1"."b"                       "b", 
       "tbl2"."c"                       "c", 
       v.time
FROM "tbl1" FULL OUTER JOIN
     "tbl2" 
     ON "tbl1"."timestamp" = "tbl2"."timestamp" CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES (COALESCE("tbl"."time", "tb2"."time")) as v(time)
ORDER BY v."time";
```

I would suggest that you write your queries so all the double quotes are not needed.

Comment: Very interesting approach also !